# LookupError: App <name_app_django> doesn't have a <Class_name_model> model

Tags: django

I have a problem when refactor existing project in Django from collection of all models from different applications into one models.py file, as the models were duplicated with different variations of the fields
so after I commented the models in the stat_table app which I moved to the common models.py I got an error: LookupError: App 'stat_table' doesn't have a 'SolarStationAddInfo' model.

Problem: LookupError: App 'stat_table' doesn't have a 'SolarStationAddInfo' model
how fix it ?

For answer and advice by this error and topics i not found how to fix in my case, and I want to share the solution to this error and what led to it by community maybe the solution will help someone

Solution:

As it turned out, when starting the stat_table application, the Redis data was accessed using the 'stations' key, and objects of the SolarStationAddInfo class were packed into it
And these Redis objects were created before my refactoring (by import that referred to the old models.py file in the stat_table application). The solution turned out to be quite simple:

1. change the imports to the SolarStationAddInfo class
2. launch the function that recreated it
   Redis objects by the key 'stations' and now, when accessing Redis, the unpacked objects are now linked by import to the new models.py in Redis, as a result, the error is completely gone

P.S. if you use Redis as a store for save objects be carefully when you refactor class models in Your django app, do not forget to recreate the Redis objects taking into account the changed imports of your models

Answer and advice by this error and topics i not found, and I want to share the solution to this error and what led to it by community maybe the solution will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

As it turned out, when starting the stat_table application, the Redis data was accessed using the 'stations' key, and objects of the SolarStationAddInfo class were packed into it And these Redis objects were created before my refactoring (by import that referred to the old models.py file in the stat_table application). The solution turned out to be quite simple:

change the imports to the SolarStationAddInfo class
launch the function that recreated it Redis objects by the key 'stations' and now, when accessing Redis, the unpacked objects are now linked by import to the new models.py in Redis, as a result, the error is completely gone
P.S. if you use Redis as a store for save objects be carefully when you refactor class models in Your django app, do not forget to recreate the Redis objects taking into account the changed imports of your models

Answer and advice by this error and topics i not found, and I want to share the solution to this error and what led to it by community maybe the solution will help someone